# Get specific addresses for names of places

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, geospatial, street-address, geocode

Ultimately what I want is to geocode an address for a large set of high schools.  For example I have:

> Destrehan high school, St. Rose Louisiana

Because I have no street information it fails if I try to geocode this.  So first I need the exact address.  This is where I'm stumped.  If I ask google or bing:

> address for Destrehan high school, St. Rose Louisiana

They both respond with

> 1 Wildcat Ln, Destrehan, LA 70047

In some sort of non-link, specific answer block which is exactly what I want.  If I ask either of their maps sites:

> Destrehan high school, St. Rose Louisiana

It again returns the right answer.  The problem is that I've tried their api services and I'm getting nowhere.  They don't return the same results.   The web api only returns links and not the "exact answer" box.  The maps service seems to require that you actually have the address.  It doesn't guess.

Any suggestions?  I'm really unfamiliar with everything about this kind of thing so even helping me with the terminology would be helpful.

EDIT:

I solved it.  Google has a specific api called "Places API".  That's what I should have been using.  Not only does it get me the address but it geocodes for me.

Comment: Feel free to add your solution as an answer and then accept it. Might even be helpful to someone else if you can give some more helpful details.

Answer (score 0):

Google has a specific api called "Places API" that you should be using. Not only will it get you the address, but it will also geocode it for you.